# LCD backlight current consumption

Tags: microcontroller, display

I am designing a power supply adapter for a  7" LCD [PH720128T003-ZBC02](https://somlabs.com/wp-content/uploads/SPF-PH720128T003-ZBC02_004.pdf).

The main voltage is 3.3V. This is enough for the internal logic regulator (VDD) and analog circuit (VCI) but not for the backlight, so I must design a step-UP DC/DC converter.

On page 9 of datasheet, the  forward current is stated If=90mA and forward voltage as Vf=19.2V.

Is this the total current for the backlight LED?

Comment: Have you thought about asking a question?

Comment: @Andyaka he did, last sentence

Comment: A bit more ambiguous before the more recent editing session @MarcusMüller with the line "This is..." rather than "Is this..."

Comment: Yes.  But the current going into the DC/DC converter will be higher than 90mA., around 90 x 19.2 / 3.3 = 525mA.

Comment: Ok, so I must deliver to DC/DC converter about 0.5A, right? I am thinking of use MP1541 Boost Converter. Is this a good choice?